# how do I call JSON multiple array functions together?

Tags: php

Here I have array numbers like [0] [1] [2] [3] .....

I have API like this

```
nodes: [

    {
    id: "1",
    kasus: "1",
    provinsi: "DKI Jakarta",
    provinsiid: "1",
    umur: "31",
    umurtext: "31",
    gender: "Perempuan",
    genderid: "1",
    status: "Sembuh",
    statusid: "1",
    wn: "WNI",
    wnid: "1",
    pengumuman: "2 Maret 2020",
    penularan: "Bertemu dengan WN Jepang yang dikonfirmasi positif di Malaysia (kasus #24)",
    rs: "RSPI Sulianto Saroso, Jakarta",
    rsid: "1"
    },
```

Here is an example of the JSON data when im var_dump

```
array(2) {
  ["nodes"]=>
  array(450) {
    [0]=>
    array(16) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["kasus"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["provinsi"]=>
      string(11) "DKI Jakarta"
      ["provinsiid"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["umur"]=>
      string(2) "31"
      ["umurtext"]=>
      string(2) "31"
      ["gender"]=>
      string(9) "Perempuan"
      ["genderid"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["status"]=>
      string(6) "Sembuh"
      ["statusid"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["wn"]=>
      string(3) "WNI"
      ["wnid"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["pengumuman"]=>
      string(12) "2 Maret 2020"
      ["penularan"]=>
      string(74) "Bertemu dengan WN Jepang yang dikonfirmasi positif di Malaysia (kasus #24)"
      ["rs"]=>
      string(29) "RSPI Sulianto Saroso, Jakarta"
      ["rsid"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(16) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["kasus"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["provinsi"]=>
      string(11) "DKI Jakarta"
      ["provinsiid"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["umur"]=>
      string(2) "64"
      ["umurtext"]=>
      string(2) "64"
      ["gender"]=>
      string(9) "Perempuan"
      ["genderid"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["status"]=>
      string(6) "Sembuh"
      ["statusid"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["wn"]=>
      string(3) "WNI"
      ["wnid"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["pengumuman"]=>
      string(12) "2 Maret 2020"
      ["penularan"]=>
      string(40) "Terhubung dengan kasus #1 (Ibu kasus #1)"
      ["rs"]=>
      string(29) "RSPI Sulianto Saroso, Jakarta"
      ["rsid"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
```

Then I tried to call all the arrays with the logic of the script that I made.
This is the code that I made from the reference that I got.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.api/URL');

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  $content = curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close($ch);

  $result = (array) json_decode($content,true);

  $count= count($result);
  foreach ($result as $value) {
    for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++)
    { 
    echo $value[$i]["rs"] . "<br>";
    echo $value[$i]["umur"] . "<br>";
    echo $value[$i]["gender"] . "<br><br>";
    }
  }
  ?>
```

When I run the code, I get output like this

```
RSPI Sulianto Saroso, Jakarta
31
Perempuan

RSPI Sulianto Saroso, Jakarta
64
Perempuan


    Notice: Undefined index: rs in C:\xampp\htdocs\CORONA\kemkes.php on line 18
Notice: Undefined index: umur in C:\xampp\htdocs\CORONA\kemkes.php on line 19
    Notice: Undefined index: gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\CORONA\kemkes.php on line 20
```

This API has 450 arrays, but only 2 arrays came out, namely [0] and [1]

Comment: results are already an array because of json decode 2nd parameter,  so no need to type cast again ` $result = (array) json_decode($content,true);`

Comment: What exactly do you need from this data? Only the 450 nodes?

Comment: @El_Vanja Hi, thanks for command, I want to get all the data arrays there, if now 450, then 451 increase, then my site will automatically become 451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you loop through the number of entries in the outer array which has the element `nodes` and probably another one that you cut off from the sample above. So, `count($result)` is 2 (you can even see in your output above: `array(2)` for the outermost array!). It seems you forgot to take the outermost 2-element array around the 450-element array into account! Or actually, you half did, because you instead of two loops inside of each other, but you are using the outer count in the inner loop which doesn't make sense.

You just need to access the inner `nodes` array directly:

```php
  foreach ($result['nodes'] as $value) {
    echo $value["rs"] . "<br>";
    echo $value["umur"] . "<br>";
    echo $value["gender"] . "<br><br>";
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, then I don't need to do For for the loop? .

Comment: thats worked , it works but why is the data double?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Maybe you still have another `foreach` around the code?